# Using a $_GET variable as img src

Tags: php, html, image, variables, src

I am trying to link an image using the same name as a $_GET variable, example bellow:

The $_GET

```
$venue = $_GET['venue'];
```

Is it possible to use '$venue' as the image src example being something like

```
<div id="imgbox">
<img src="$venue.jpg" alt="venueimage" height="150" width="250">
</div>
```

My attempts so far have been unsuccessful, is it possible in a similar way to this or is there an alterantive?
Thankyou

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You forgot your PHP tags and echo statement:

```
<div id="imgbox">
<img src="<?php echo $venue; ?>.jpg" alt="venueimage" height="150" width="250">
</div>
```

or shorthand:

```
<div id="imgbox">
<img src="<?= $venue; ?>.jpg" alt="venueimage" height="150" width="250">
</div>
```

As pointed out by Quentin we should take this a step further and sanitize our output:

```
<div id="imgbox">
<img src="<?= htmlspecialchars($venue); ?>.jpg" alt="venueimage" height="150" width="250">
</div>
```

Comment: **Danger**: This code is [vulnerable to XSS](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Cross-site_Scripting_(XSS)). User input needs escaping before being inserted into an HTML document!.

Comment: In addition to John Conde above, you also forgot sanity checking. I can now inject javascript into your page, which could lead to me stealing cookies or other information from users who click on a fabricated link. You will want to ensure a file with that name actually exists ([file_exists](http://php.net/file_exists)) and that it is actually within the current directory.

Comment: Thank you for the quick reply, very useful and all solved!

Thanks for the other comments, i intended this as an example and will ensure it is protected.

Answer (score -1):

You should be able to use `<img src="<?php echo $venue; ?>.jpg" alt="venueimage" height="150" width="250">`

I forgot to sanitize the code as well. You would need to add:

`<img src="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($venue); ?>.jpg" alt="venuimage" height="150" width="250">`

Comment: **Danger**: This code is [vulnerable to XSS](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Cross-site_Scripting_(XSS)). User input needs escaping before being inserted into an HTML document!.